# gulp-4 concate multiple js files into one: Error Identifier has already been defined

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am using Nodejs- v12.9.0 & gulp-4.0.2

I want to concatenate & minify multiple js files from different src directories and bundle then into a single JS file.
It does concatenate, minify & generates a single js file.
While running this generated js file it gives below error because in almost all the js files we have this module const fs = require('fs').

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

Getting below error

```
SyntaxError: Identifier 'fs' has already been declared
```

gulp task:

```
function copyOtherJs(){
    return src(['main.js','app.js', 'src/*.js'])
        .pipe(terser({ parse: { bare_returns: false}, mangle: false }))//{ parse: { bare_returns: true } 
        .pipe(concat('srcJs.js'))
        .pipe(dest('dist/src'));
}
```

How to overcome this error while running my minified js file.

Answer (score 0):

Bundling is generally used for client-side files. There's no reason to bundle and concatenate server-side code, it won't make anything noticeably faster or easier to manage. The only good use case I can think of for trying to bundle your whole server into one file might be obfuscation, but that's not what it looks like you're doing. If on the other hand you have those declarations in client-side code, that also wouldn't work, because those modules don't exist in the browser.

Comment: Yes this program is just a utility which calls APIs and collect data in CSV files. I am concatenating all js files so that my pipeline can copy this  single minified on agent machine along with dependencies (node_modules). 
Any idea how to deal with these global const which are declared in multiple js files and with same name ????

Comment: You could write a script to strip them out, or change them to `var`s. Concatenating and minifying server-side code isn't common so I don't know if there are any common tools to to do this. The normal process would be to just copy everything up as is, either as a ZIP or some other archive, or cloned from the Git repo.